# How do I remote desktop into a windows 8 pc to a live.com user account without being prompted for username and password?

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, domain

How do I remote desktop into a windows 8 pc to a live.com user account without being prompted for username and password?

I've tried a number of user name and domain combinations, but they all fail on the first try. If they send me to the windows 8 login screen, then I can then type in username@live.com to login correctly.

I'm connecting from a mac, but I don't think that that would make a difference.

When I try:

```
username (without @live.com)
password
live.com
```

It returns the username or password is incorrect, but shows the windows 8 login screen. There I can login with the username@live.com and password on the windows 8 login screen, and I can get in.

I've obviously tried putting live.com as the domain, as well as @live.com in the username.

EDIT: It might be MicrosoftAccount\username@live.com

Comment: Is the 'Always ask for credentials box' ticked?

Comment: @GuyThomas I looked on the client and server and can't find this anywhere. It is not on the mac client? I checked and it's up to date

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a MAC to check

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows 8 desktop, go to Remote Settings ("Control Panel" | "System and Security" | "System" | "Remote settings" in the left pane)  and change the value to "Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop (less secure)"

Comment: I can never log in on the first attempt from remote desktop. But I can on the second. So I don't think that this setting would matter - do you agree? @JorgeMoura